# How can I learn Math intuitively?

Tags: axioms, philosophy, learning

I am currently a Junior in High School. I am in an Intermediate Algebra class, but my teacher does not always explain things in a way I can understand. I like to learn Math intuitively, but my teacher seems to just throw us formulas and rules, and expects us to use them without understanding why they work.

For example, when learning exponential properties, we learned $a^na^m=a^{m+n}$. I asked why this is, and my teacher gave me the old "It is what it is" explanation. I played around a bit with these variables later, and I intuitively reasoned it out. I figured since $a^n$ is just $a \times a \times a \dotsc$ ($n$ times), and $a^m$ is just $a \times a \times a \dotsc$ ($m$ times), then by the commutative axiom I could just combine them into one big $a \times a \times a \times a \times a \dotsc$ ($m+n$ times).

Now that I am getting into more advanced topics, I am worried I will not be able to reason some properties or concepts out myself. I realize that most kids do not really need or want to know why these axioms and theorems hold true, but I am a bit more inquisitive than others, and I have a desire to pursue a degree in Mathematics or possibly Physics.

When you learn new information, is there a certain way you make it intuitive for yourself? Is there any website or textbook than can give you a proof or a visual display of why certain properties work? (other than things that are completely obvious/self evident such as $a=a$ and $a\times0=0$) Are there certain techniques you can recommend me for understanding my newfound knowledge? Is there study techniques I should practice? Should I really care about Mathematical intuition and philosophy — am I being too curious?

I really have a drive to learn, but I feel like if I cant grasp why certain properties hold true in Arithmetic and Algebra, I will not be able to intuitively understand concepts that I am taught later on when I take Calculus or Statistics.

Comment: Also as a side note, I do not know Latex or Mathjax (I am planning to learn soon). Please excuse my formatting, and if anyone wants to kindly edit my equations and format them properly, I would be grateful.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've been getting some awful teachers. Especially with high school topics, its important to understand *why* things are the way they are. If you're having trouble with some topics, you can always feel free to post them.

Comment: I'd say, intuition comes from yourself. No one can teach you that. Also for understanding you need to be somewhat smart. However, you can be assisted in understanding and that is sometimes necessary - may you be the smartest in school. So, if your teacher is not capable of this, I think there are only two possibilities to deal with that: either you find somebody else to talk to (parents, another teacher, class mates, this site, etc) or you read books. What about the book you use in school? But there are surely many other books on the market. Unfortunately, I cannot recommend you any.

Comment: I have edited your question to introduce $\LaTeX$ formatting. Please do learn it, it will greatly help you in the future, considering your desire to go in this field, besides its syntax is plain intuitive, especially for simple typesetting like for your formulae. You can [view the results of the edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1699591/edit) to see how simple it's done. Additionally, you may consider [following this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to familiarize yourself with more advanced techniques.

Comment: People often don't explain the intuition, for some reason.  But the intuition is out there, you just have to search for it (or find it yourself).  You're not being too curious.

Comment: I think your question was wrongly closed, because it is relevant to many people. Please edit, removing all explicit personal information, so that reads as generally applicable. To quote the close message `If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.`

Comment: Another thing you can do is ask specific questions on this site. e.g. Using your example, you could ask: *"Why is $a^{nm}=a^{m+n}$?"* (include your reasoning so far: people like to see you tried, and get an idea of where you are). BTW a way to learn mathjax, a bit at a time, is to right-click (or long tap) on some, and choose `Show Math As`, `TeX Commands`. Try it on the e.g. I gave (`a^{nm}=a^{m+n}`, add a `$` before and after). NB This might no longer be needed by you, but the point of stackexchange sites is it can help someone else with the same problem! [Hence, the rewrite suggested above]